# Querying files with python objects

Tags: python, arrays, object

I have 2 files that I would consider to be like two tables of a database.

They consider a string for each line with python objects of the type:
    {u'timestamp': 1379941920.923155, u'code': u'xxx', u'code_id': u'xxx', u'greeting': u'xxx'}

So how do I transform them into something I can work with and query in python. Optimally I'd like to cross them on the 'code' key but that's along the line. First I need to have them parsed into objects in my python code.

Comment: You can use json module, to convert this.

Comment: @Naster: have you tried ? This isn't valid json, it's Python's `repr()` of a `dict` with unicode keys and values (Python 2.x obviously).

Answer (score 2):

Those strings look to be the `repr`s of Python dicts. The inverse or `repr` is generally `eval`, but using `eval` on data that you don't trust completely is probably unwise. That's because if somebody inserted a line like `{u'code': __import__("os").system("rm -Rf /")}` it would try to delete your hard drive. (Don't try this!)

A safer alternative is [`ast.literal_eval`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval), which works like `eval` but will only handle literals like strings, lists and dictionaries (and not function calls!). So, a basic function to get a list of dictionaries from a file would be:

```
import ast

def read_dict_file(filename):
    with open(filename) as f:
        return [ast.literal_eval(line) for line in f]
```

As for doing more processing on your data to let you treat it like a database, I think the matter depends on how large your data set is and how complicated the stuff you want to do is.

If it's pretty simple stuff and you don't have a lot of data, you can probably do something simple with dictionaries keyed on whatever your relevant fields are and get reasonable results.

On the other hand, if you want to do some more complicated processing of your data, or if you have a lot of it, you should probably just put your data in a real database and use its already tested and scalable APIs rather than writing your own. Python comes with [`sqlite3`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html) (and probably some other self-contained database modules that I'm not familiar with) so there's probably no need to install new software even if you have fairly heavy needs.

Answer (score 0):

`"{u'timestamp': 1379941920.923155, u'code': u'xxx', u'code_id': u'xxx', u'greeting': u'xxx'}"` is what you get from printing the `repr()` of a Python `dict`, and his the litteral Python code that would create the same `dict`. The **totally unsafe** way to turn this back into a `dict` is to use `eval()`, but that's something you shouldn't do, really. The three golden rules about `eval()` are:

1. don't use it
2. don't use it
3. for advanced programmers only: don't use it.

Now you're warned.

Since the syntax is quite close to json, you can more safely use `json.loads()` after some simple preprocessing on your string:

```
import json

# your original line of text:
line = "{u'timestamp': 1379941920.923155, u'code': u'xxx', u'code_id': u'xxx', u'greeting': u'xxx'}\n"

# making it proper json, quick&dirty way, likely to break on some other examples,
# would need a proper regexp
line = line.replace("u'", "'").replace("'", '"')

# and now let's make it a python `dict`:
mydict = json.loads(line)
```

Comment: Blckknght beat me, and his answer is far better.